# Where I am I liable for taxes?

Tags: united-states, taxes, united-kingdom

I have a business which offers paid subscription-based access to a piece of software hosted in the cloud (i.e. the user doesn't install the software on their PC but accesses it via their web browser).

This business is registered in the UK. If I were to host the application on a server situated in the US what would be the tax implications of this? The server would not be owned by my company but owned by a hosting company to whom my company pays an on-going fee.

Comment: Are *you* situated in the US/were situated when you developed the software/is a US citizen/green card holder/own a US-registered corporation through which this runs?

Comment: I am situated in the UK and always have been. The business is registered in the UK and is not run through a US corporation.

Answer (score 2):

You will have to pay your taxes in the UK not USA. For tax purposes it is the company's tax residency not where the server is located. You are just hiring a server in USA. Take for example a CDN being used for your same service then would you pay taxes in 300 different countries if you use Akamai? Does not work that way.